# Kubuntu 20.04 LTS watch movies directly from samba network

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, smb

I want to watch movies from my local FTP or SMB. When I double click I need to wait when kioexec copy file to local cache. Is it possible to watch movies without wasting time for copying?

Comment: What program do you use to watch the film? I use VLC and do this all the time. My connections are SAMBA.

Comment: I use VLC and Celluloid, but I preffer VLC. Do you have any special settings in VLC?

Comment: Factory default did nothing.

Comment: When I open Samba and double click system starts  copying file to cache and I need to wait till it's finish.

Comment: Sorry have not idea what you are doing. I do not know what you mean by open samba. From the file manager you choose the file and select open with VLC. Done.

Comment: I use Dolphin file manager. Did you install fresh version or upgrade from previous version? Do you have any special settings for SMB or just type SMB://IP/DISC?

Comment: I do not know that file manager maybe it works different. I installed and configured Samba to allow access to the dir I wanted and that is all I did.

Comment: Thanks for clarification I have this problem only in Kubuntu. I checked in Ubuntu and previously use Linux Mint and there wasn't this issue.